# Webpack 4, process is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

All of a sudden a project that worked fine on webpack 4 now breaks on all browsers while on dev.

I am using
Node v16.3.0  & npm v8.1.3

The page loads, the terminal gives out no error and it seems to work, the page can be interacted with for a few seconds then it frezees and the console on the browsers throws:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

The build still works well for production it's only breaking on dev.

I have researched and tried everything, changed to different node version use the `process` plugin, it does not matter always comes back with the same error on the browser console.

This is my webpack.config.js

```
// Module paths
const path = require('path')
// File System module
const fs = require('fs')
// Main webpack bundler
const webpack = require('webpack')
// Merger for webpack configurations
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
// Created html for bundle
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
// Add Tags
const HtmlWebpackTagsPlugin = require('html-webpack-tags-plugin')
// CSS Linter
const StylelintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin')
// On screen error console
const ErrorOverlayPlugin = require('error-overlay-webpack-plugin')
// Tidy up plugings after ise
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
// Copy folder
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
// Module loaders
const load = require('./webpack.modules')
// Get metas
const { links, metas } = require('../meta/meta-data')

// Paths
const paths = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, '../../app'),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, '../../public')
}

// Main module
const commonConfig = merge([
  {
    context: paths.app,
    resolve: {
      unsafeCache: true,
      symlinks: false
    },
    output: {
      path: paths.dist,
      pathinfo: true
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlPlugin({
        template: `${paths.app}/index.html`,
        inject: true
      }),
      // Style linter
      new StylelintPlugin({
        context: `${paths.app}/styles`,
        syntax: 'scss',
        emitErrors: false,
        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'stylelint.config.js')
      })
    ]
  },
  load.LintJS({
    include: `${paths.app}/scripts/*`,
    options: {
      emitWarning: true,
      failOnWarning: false,
      failOnError: true,
      fix: true,
      cache: true,
      formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
      configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'eslint.config.js')
    }
  })
])
// Production module
const productionConfig = merge([
  {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: false,
    stats: {
      assets: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false
    },
    entry: {
      app: paths.app + '/scripts/index.jsx',
      styles: paths.app + '/styles/index.scss'
    },
    output: {
      filename: 'static/scripts/[name].bundle.[contenthash:8].js'
    },
    optimization: {
      runtimeChunk: 'single',
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
        maxAsyncRequests: 30,
        maxSize: 100000,
        minSize: 0,
        cacheGroups: {
          defaultVendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name(module) {
              // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
              // or node_modules/packageName
              const packageName = module.context.match(
                /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/
              )[1]
              // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
              return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    performance: {
      maxEntrypointSize: 470000, // in bytes
      maxAssetSize: 470000, // in bytes
      hints: 'warning' // 'error' or false are valid too
    },
    cache: true,
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackTagsPlugin({ links, metas }),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          from: `${paths.app}/images/favicon`,
          to: `${paths.dist}/static/images/favicon`
        }
      ])
    ]
  },
  // HTML
  load.Html(true),
  // JS
  load.Scripts({
    include: `${paths.app}/scripts`,
    options: {
      configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'babel.config.js'),
      cacheDirectory: true
    }
  }),
  load.MinifyJS({
    extractComments: true,
    cache: true,
    parallel: true,
    sourceMap: false,
    terserOptions: {
      extractComments: 'all',
      parse: { ecma: 8 },
      compress: {
        ecma: 5,
        warnings: false,
        comparisons: false,
        drop_console: true
      },
      mangle: { safari10: true },
      output: {
        ecma: 5,
        comments: false,
        ascii_only: true
      }
    }
  }),
  // CSS
  load.ExtractCSS({
    include: `${paths.app}/styles`,
    options: {
      filename: 'static/styles/[name].min.[contenthash:8].css'
    }
  }),
  load.CSS({
    include: `${paths.app}/node_modules/react-calendar/`
  }),
  load.MinifyCSS({
    options: {
      discardComments: { removeAll: true }
    }
  }),
  // Images
  load.Images({
    include: `${paths.app}/images`,
    options: {
      name: 'static/images/[name].[contenthash:8].[ext]',
      limit: 1000,
      esModule: false
    }
  }),
  load.Fonts({
    include: `${paths.app}/fonts`,
    options: {
      name: 'static/fonts/[name].[contenthash:8].[ext]',
      limit: 5000
    }
  }),
  load.OptimizeImages({
    options: {
      mozjpeg: { progressive: true },
      gifsicle: { interlaced: false },
      optipng: { optimizationLevel: 4 },
      pngquant: { quality: [0.75, 0.9], speed: 3 }
    }
  })
])

// Development module
const developmentConfig = merge([
  {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [paths.app + '/scripts/index.jsx', paths.app + '/styles/index.scss'],
    cache: true,
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackTagsPlugin({
        links: [
          {
            path: 'data:,',
            attributes: { rel: 'icon' }
          }
        ]
      }),

      new ErrorOverlayPlugin(),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
      }
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          default: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // Dev server main settings
  load.DevServer({
    host: 'ranks.local',
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:4000',
        secure: false
      }
    },
    http2: true,
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/localhost+3-key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/localhost+3.pem')
    }
  }),
  // HTML
  load.Html(),
  // JS
  load.Scripts({
    include: `${paths.app}/scripts`,
    options: {
      configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'babel.config.js')
    }
  }),
  // CSS
  load.CSS({
    include: `${paths.app}/node_modules/react-calendar/`
  }),
  load.Styles({
    include: `${paths.app}/styles`
  }),
  // Images
  load.Images({
    include: `${paths.app}/images`,
    options: {
      esModule: false,
      limit: 0
    }
  }),
  // Fonts
  load.Fonts({
    include: `${paths.app}/fonts`,
    options: {
      name: `fonts/[name].[hash:8].[ext]`
    }
  })
])

// Merge modules
module.exports = (env) =>
  merge(commonConfig, env === 'dev' ? developmentConfig : productionConfig)
```

And these are my package.json scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.config.js --env dev --color",
    "build": "webpack --config=config/webpack.config.js --mode=production --progress"
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration has this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }),
```

in `productionConfig`, but not in `developmentConfig`.

If your code is accessing `process.env.NODE_ENV` somewhere, it will succeed in production but fail in development, which is consistent with what you're experiencing.

Try adding `DefinePlugin` to the plugins list in developmentConfig and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Already have but fails just the same, besides I never had it on dev before and it worked well

Comment: Interesting. Have you confirmed that all instances of `process.env.<SOMETHING>` in your code are covered in the DefinePlugin configuration in your *developmentConfig*?

Comment: What other instances are there, and how can I confirm that? The `DefinedPlugin` was not used before on `developmentConfig` and it all worked fine

Comment: "What other instances are there" -> search through your project's files with `grep -rn process.env src/*" (if your code is in the src folder), or your IDE's built-in search feature

Comment: If another dev working on this project added DefinePlugin to the `productionConfig` of your project recently, but forgot to also add it to `developmentConfig`, that would also cause the situation you're in.

Comment: I am the only one using this repo, and there never was `DefinePlugin` on the `developmentConfig` also as per my answer it works and still there is no `DefinePlugin` on dev

Answer (score 0):

I am completely buffled by this, it has kind of fixed by itself and I don't know how.

I installed this

```sh
$ npm i -D react-error-overlay@6.0.9
```

And then it worked but this package does not show on the `package.json`